# How can i post the ngCart checkout button on http using php and angular js?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, git

I do not know how can i post my data's into a new php page and this is my code:

```
<ngcart-checkout service="http" settings="{ url:'./checkout.php' }">Checkout </ngcart-checkout>
```

but the original code from the ngCart docs is

```
<ngcart-checkout service="http" settings="{ url:'/checkout' }"></ngcart-checkout>
```

the ngcart-checkout code is

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="checkout()" ng-disabled="!ngCart.getTotalItems()" ng-transclude>Checkout</button>
```

still it does not redirect me unto checkout.php and so i go to the ngcart.js and the codes for the checkout using http post is

```
   .service('ngCart.fulfilment.http', ['$http', 'ngCart', function($http,        ngCart){

     this.checkout = function(settings){
         return $http.post(settings.url,
             {data:ngCart.toObject()})
     }
  }])
```

so again my problem was how can i redirect my checkout button unto the checkout.php and how can i post those items unto the checkout.php using http post?

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you are looking for something like this in your ngcart.js file

```
    <script>
    .service('ngCart.fulfilment.log', ['$http', 'ngCart', function($http, ngCart){

    this.checkout = function(settings){
        //var item_data = ngCart['$cart']['items'], message;
        //return $http.post('checkout.php',
        //    {data:item_data});
        var postData = 'item_data='+JSON.stringify(ngCart['$cart']['items']);
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'checkout.php',
            data: postData,
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

        }).success(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }).error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}])</script>
```

Comment: thank you but how can i post this using php? sorry im a noob on programming especially when transferring data's to php.

Comment: This will parse the cart data to json in your browser, I am also trying to work out how to get the cart data to send in an email on checkout :)